# How to pass data through firebase-functions to Paypal?

Tags: ios, paypal, google-cloud-functions

I have an app on both Android an iOS on same Firebase project.  The last part of the app is to send data from my app to firebase-function then to PayPal.  It works in Android but not in iOS.  Please see the code below.

I have even spoken with PayPal but they think it's the iOS code.  I have posts in GitHub, PayPal, Stack Overflow, etc with no resolution in sight.

Basically, when I press a button - GET PAYOUT, the payoutRequest() method is executed.  It should send the 'uid' and 'email' to the function and then to PayPal.

The PayPal SDK is included in the function.

It does not send the data to PayPal but it is recognized in the function (https function not a callable function)

**Android code working**

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json"); ProgressDialog progress;

private void payoutRequest() {

progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Processing your payout ...");
progress.setMessage("Please Wait .....");
progress.setCancelable(false);
progress.show();

// HTTP Request ....
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

// in json - we need variables for the hardcoded uid and Email
JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();

try {
    postData.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    postData.put("email", mPayoutEmail.getText().toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Request body ...
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postData.toString());

// Build Request ...
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Your Token")
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        // something went wrong right off the bat
        progress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        // response successful ....
        // refers to response.status('200') or ('500')
        int responseCode = response.code();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            switch(responseCode) {
                case 200:
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                            "Payout Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    break;

                case 500:
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                            "Error: no payout available", Snackbar
                                    .LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                            "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                    "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        progress.dismiss();
    }
});
}
```

**Firebase-Function: index.js**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

paypal.configure({
    mode: 'sandbox',
    client_id: functions.config().paypal.client_id,
    client_secret: functions.config().paypal.client_secret
})

exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
    var price  = snapshot.child('price').val();
    var pushId = context.params.pushId;

    return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
 });


function getPayoutsPending(uid) {
    return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        if(snap === null){
            throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
        }
        var array = [];
        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if (element.val() === true) {
                    array.push(element.key);
                }
            });
        }
        return array;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

function getPayoutsAmount(array) {
    return admin.database().ref('history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        var value = 0.0;
        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if(array.indexOf(element.key) > -1) {
                        if(element.child('price').val() !== null){
                            value += element.child('price').val();
                        }
                }
            });
            return value;
        }
        return value;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

function updatePaymentsPending(uid, paymentId) {
    return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        if(snap === null){
            throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
        }

        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if(element.val() === true) {
                    admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history/' + element.key).set( {
                        timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                        paymentId: paymentId
                    });
                    admin.database().ref('history/' + element.key + '/driverPaidOut').set(true);
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

exports.payout = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return getPayoutsPending(request.body.uid)
        .then(array => getPayoutsAmount(array))
        .then(value => {
            var valueTrunc = parseFloat(Math.round((value * 0.75) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            const sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
            const sync_mode = 'false';
            const payReq = JSON.stringify({
                sender_batch_header: {
                    sender_batch_id: sender_batch_id,
                    email_subject: "You have a payment"
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        recipient_type: "EMAIL",
                        amount: {
                            value: valueTrunc,
                            currency: "CAD"
                        },
                        receiver: request.body.email,
                        note: "Thank you.",
                        sender_item_id: "Payment"
                    }
                ]
            });

            return paypal.payout.create(payReq, sync_mode, (error, payout) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.warn(error.response);
                    response.status('500').end();
                    throw error;
                }
                console.info("uid: " + request.body.uid + " email: " + request.body.email) // testing
                console.info("payout created");
                console.info(payout);
                return updatePaymentsPending(request.body.uid, sender_batch_id)
            });
        }).then(() => {
            response.status('200').end();
            return null;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

**IOS Code: payoutRequest()**

```
var params: Parameters = ["uid": FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid as Any, "email": txtPayoutEmail.text!]

    let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Your Token",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    params = params as! Dictionary<String, String>
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil, error == nil else {
            print("no data found: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("status code: \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response: \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let parsedObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments)
        print(parsedObject)
    }

    task.resume()
```

**What happens**

When the method (payoutRequest()) is executed, the logs in the Firebase Function shows that the 'uid' and 'email' parameters are retained:

[image: firebase logs]

as you can see on the 3rd line of the console, the uid and email parameters are retained.

The next thing to happen, is the data (parameters) should be sent to Paypal and a notification sent to the email address, stating a payment is received, like this:

[image: paypal notification]

but no such notification is there.

If I check the API calls for Sandbox, I see this:

[image: PayPal API Call for Sandbox]

Then 4 hours to a day later, I get this error in logs, basically, it got bounced back because PayPal did not retain the data sent:

[image: firebase logs 2]

Comment: Is this essentially the same problem as [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925577/initiating-a-firebase-function-with-paypal)?

Comment: yes, still not solved.  I had opened a post at apple.stackexchange thinking they could help.

Comment: I don't think they take programming questions there. Indeed, if you are cross-posting the question in several places on the web, please include in each one links to all the others. This will allow readers to check whether any of your duplicates have already been answered, to prevent them wasting their time on an answer when you already have one elsewhere.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know.  Still learning lol

Comment: On which Firebase payment plan are you? Spark, Flame or Blaze? https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Blaze payment plan

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you have here on the iOS code is that the value of `params` should be of type `[String: String]` (that's the required type for POST data).

I'm referring to this line specifically:

> var params: Parameters = ["uid": FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid as Any, "email": txtPayoutEmail.text!]

Try by casting the uid to String instead:

> var params: Parameters = ["uid": FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid as String, "email": txtPayoutEmail.text!]

Comment: Ok I did as you suggested but no difference in the end outcome.  Also if I print out data --> 0 bytes

Comment: Very odd. Can you try encoding `params` using `JSONEncoder().encode()`?

Comment: This is what I did:
do {
            let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(params)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
            print("jsonString: \(jsonString ?? "")")
        } catch {
            print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
        }
result :: jsonString: {"uid":"o2a30PjFufSBYtSIUR5UWFpwPcr1","email":"me@me.com"}

Comment: Did it solve the issue, No unfortunately.  Did I put in right spot?  I put the above code just above the code "let task = session...."